# Seaborn KDE Plots with Different Colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to create a plot using Seaborn Pairgrid and plot the KDE plots in different colors. When I plot the upper triangle and diagonal, it gives me the different colors I want. When I plot the lower diagonal, all the KDE plots are in the same color. Is there a way to get this to work using the KDE plots as shown on the bottom triangle? Below is the code used to produce the attached image.

```
test = sns.PairGrid(data[::1000], hue='label', palette="Set2", vars=['T1', 'Fl', 'T2', 'HF', 'LF', 'FW'], size=5, aspect=0.8)
test.map_upper(plt.scatter)
test.map_diag(sns.kdeplot)
test.map_lower(sns.kdeplot, shade=True, shade_lowest=False)
```

Comment: You mention "the attached image" but nothing is visible to me.  Did you mean to have something else here?  Also, it would be useful to have an example dataset so that others could look at the code more specifically

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with data that illustrates the issue referred to here.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
g = sns.PairGrid(iris, vars = ["sepal_length", "sepal_width",    "petal_length", "petal_width"], hue = "species", diag_sharey=False)
g.map_lower(sns.kdeplot)
g.map_upper(plt.scatter, edgecolor='white')
g.map_diag(sns.kdeplot, lw=3)
```